# How to update the whole list when just one element is modified outside in a class in c#?

Tags: c#, class, list

```
class Foo
{
    public List<object> mylist;

    public int num;
    public string name;
    public bool isIt;


    public Foo()
    { 
        mylist = new List<object>();
        mylist.Add(num);
        mylist.Add(name);
        mylist.Add(isIt);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Foo my = new Foo();
        my.isIt = true;
        my.mylist[0] = 5;
        my.mylist[1] = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine("" + my.mylist[2]);  => returns false instead of true
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put the whole description in the subject, keep the subject concise and explain in the body of your post what your question is.

Comment: bool variable by default is false, so it returns false.

Comment: No, I think I didn't make it clear. I was asking how to update an element in a list, when the element gets updated outide.
my.isIt = true; <= updated outside
my.mylist[2] = true; <= updated inside the lit

Comment: It's a case of using reference type logic, when you're clearly using value types. Please take a look at James Michael Hare's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your list will always have an item at index 2:

```
    private bool _isIt;

    public List<object> mylist;

    public bool isIt{
      get{return _isIt;}
      set{
         _isIt = value;
         myList[2] = value;
       }
     }
```

Comment: There you go! exactly what I wanted. To update the list when element gets modified outside. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code is not returning true is because your list is holding different references than the fields when you change the value using the field instead of the list.

In your constructor when you call:

```
mylist.Add(isIt);
```

It adds the value `false` boxed in an `object`.

Then in your `Main`, when you do:

```
my.isIt = true;
```

You are modifying the field, but the list still refers to the boxed object you added in the constructor.  If you want to change the value stored in the list, you have to reference the list like you did originally:

```
my.myList[2] = true;
```

But this will not link the fields to the list, because they refer to different copies of the data (in the case of the string, different copies of a reference to an immutable type).  You can change what one points to, but it won't automatically change what the other points to.

The same thing would be true if you tried to set any of the other fields:

```
    my.isIt = true;
    my.num = 5;
    my.name = "Hello";
```

They will still show their original values in the list of: false, 0, and "".

If you really want to do this, you can do something like Jamie Dixon suggests.

Comment: Did as Jamie suggested. Thanks for explaining it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You use the value of isIt (default: `false`) in the constructor, before you set the value of isIt on the row after. It will always default to false, unless you specifically change it, or change your logic. Because it is a value type, the value will be copied, not referenced.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist.Add(isIt);
```

Here you added a VALUE of isIt to the list, not the variable itself.
thats why when you do:

```
my.isIt = true;
```

you update the variable, but the list will stay with old value.

Answer (score 0):

my.mylist[2] is false, that's why it's returning false... could you clarify your question?

By declaring:

```
public bool isIt;
```

The default value will be false.

you could do:

```
public bool isIt = true;
```

to default it to true.

Setting my.isIt = true; after you've already added the default of false to the collection with mylist.Add(isIt); will not change the value of what you added at my.mylist[2]. You would need to set my.mylist[2] = true after already adding it to the list collection.

Comment: I know that I didn't even modify the list, but wondering how if I just modify one element it should be reflected on whole list. Like, by doing my.isIt = true; => should make the 3rd element in the list in object my to be true. Thanks.

Comment: @mservidio, not just bool, for all value types. =)

Comment: haha, yes thanks =) I realized how wrong that comment was and I quickly deleted it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 my.myList[2].isIt = true;
```

You didn't set the right item.

Comment: Wrong. isIt is a property of my, not the object in the List<object>.

Comment: ok... got it.. so in this case you're list is getting instantiated and the third value in your list is instantiated with a field which has a default value of false.  You then update the field-- I wouldn't expect the item in your list to change.